# Swift map change points if change SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapbox

I'm trying to work with Mapbox.

I have created a point on my map and show from file

I want that when `SegmentedControl` is changed, `item.type` is changed accordingly and get correct data

For example if press 0 case -> make 0 == item.type

I create custom points

```
func addItemsToMap(features: [MGLPointFeature]) {

    guard let style = mapView.style else { return }
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "mapPoints", features: features, options: nil)
    style.addSource(source)

    let colors = [
            "black": MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.black)
    ]
    let circles = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "mapPoints-circles", source: source)
    circles.circleColor = MGLSourceStyleFunction(interpolationMode: .identity,
                                                     stops: colors,
                                                     attributeName: "color",
                                                     options: nil)
    circles.circleRadius = MGLStyleValue(interpolationMode: .exponential,
                                             cameraStops: [2: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 5),
                                                           7: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 8)],
                                             options: nil)
    circles.circleStrokeWidth = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 2)
    circles.circleStrokeColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.white)

    style.addLayer(circles)
}
```

Put data to mapbox

```
func test(number: Int) {

    guard let documentsDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let urlBar = documentsDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("Persons.json")

    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: urlBar)
        //Переводим их в модель
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CollectionTest.self, from: jsonData)
        let coll: CollectionTest = result
        let features = parseJSONItems(collection: coll, number: number)

        addItemsToMap(features: features)
        print(features)
    } catch { print("Error while parsing: \(error)") }
}
```

Get data from file

```
func parseJSONItems(collection: CollectionTest, number: Int) -> [MGLPointFeature] {

    var features = [MGLPointFeature]()
    for item in collection.prices {
            if item.type == number {
...get data to annotation and location
let feature = MGLPointFeature()
            feature.coordinate = coordinate
            feature.title = "\(name)"
            feature.attributes = [
                "color" : color,
                "name" : "\(name)"
            ]
            features.append(feature)
        }
                    }
                }}}
    }
    return features
}
```

I need to change `number` from `0` to `4`, because in data I have type from `0` to `4` and points need to change from `0`-`4` if `SegmentedControl` is changed

in `SegmentedControl` I have

```
@objc func change(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
        test(number: 0)
        case 1:
        test(number: 1)
        case 2:
        ttest(number: 2)
        case 3:
        test(number: 3)
        case 4:
        test(number: 4)
        default:
        test(number: 2)
    }
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    styleToggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(change(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    test(number: 2)
}
```

When app run - works good and show all data == type 2

But when I change button in `SegmentedControl` to `case 0` or others - I get a crash and in console prints

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'MGLRedundantSourceIdentifierException', reason: 'Source mapPoints already exists'

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add a source to your map that already exists. In order to avoid this message, you will want to either:

1. Check for the existence of a source before adding it to your style. In your use case, maybe name your sources `mapPoints-circles-\(number)`. If the source already exists, reuse it.
2. Add the source to the map one time (preferably within the initial [`-mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.3.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html)). In order to create new layers from it layer, you can access the source from the map's style.

If the points come from a source with an identifier `my-source`, you would try:

```
guard let source = style.source(withIdentifier: "my-source") else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

when clicking a segment, remove all markers which are already present in the map
then add new markers

You can use map.removeLayer(marker); to remove the marker (an ILayer object).

Comment: Im create remove func and use in cases       

`func remove() {
        if let annotations = self.mapView.annotations {
            for _annotation in annotations {
                if let annotation = _annotation as? [MGLPointFeature]
                {
                    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotation)
                
                }
            }
        }
    }`

But it does’t help me and error still shows